# How does hardware affect the performance of malloc\new on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, performance, memory-management, benchmarking

I am working on the performance of a c++ application on Windows 7, which is doing a lot of computation and a lot of of small allocations. Basically I observed a bottleneck using visual studio sampling profiler and it come down to the parsing of a file and creation of a huge tree structure of the type

```
class TreeStruct : std::map<key, TreeStructPtr>
{
   SomeMetadata p;
   int* buff;
   int buffsize;
}
```

1. There are ten of thousand of these structure created during the parsing
2. The buffer is not that big, 1 byte to few hundred bytes

The profiler report that the most costly functions is

1. free (13 000 exclusive samples, 38% Exclusive Samples)
2. operator new (13 000 exclusive samples, 38% Exclusive Samples)
3. realloc (4000 exclusive samples, 13% Exclusive Samples)

I managed to optimize and to reduce allocations to

1. operator new (2200 exclusive samples, 48% Exclusive Samples)
2. free (1770 exclusive samples, 38% Exclusive Samples)
3. some function (73 exclusive samples, 1.5% Exclusive Samples)

When I measure the client waiting time (ie a client wait for the action to process with a stopwatch) The ***installed version*** on my machine **went from 85s of processing time to 16s of processing time**, which is great. I proceed to test on the most powerful machine we have and was stunned that the non optimized version **took only `3.5s` while to optimized around `2s`**. Same executable, same operating system...

## Question: How is such a disparity possible on two modern machines?

Here are the specs :
85s to 16s machine

[image]

3.5s to 2s machine

[image]

The processing is mono-threaded.

Comment: Allocations are mostly a operating system thing. Besides that, allocations are generally expensive. It is often better to allocate memory pools once and reuse them. Small allocations involve quite some housekeeping overhead inside the kernel. It can also be related to the paging and general system load.

Comment: Jan Henke is correct. It's best to allocate all the structures at once, before you need them, then keep them in a collection of some sort. Then just grab them out of the collection when you need them. When you don't need them anymore, put them back in the collection and mark them as available.

Comment: You have more cache and a faster memory in the second machine. What is the amount of memory allocated dinamically?

Comment: *"I am working on the performance of a c++ application [...], which is doing [...] a lot of of small allocations"* That's likely your biggest issue. Even though heap implementations in the CRT constantly improved over the years, allocations still come with quite an overhead. It's usually going to improve performance significantly, if you avoid doing lots of small allocations (this is an area where .NET outperforms native C++ programs easily by an order of magnitude). Would be interesting to see if a .NET implementation that P/Invokes into a native compute kernel can deliver better performance.

Comment: Inadequate bench-marking is forever the usual reason.  You'll see such a difference when you ran your slow version with the debug heap enabled.  Also, what *should* be slow is reading of the file.  Many, many times slower than allocating memory.  Standard mistake is to run the program repeatedly, it no longer reads the file from the disk but from the file system cache.  Last but not least is the amount of paging file space available, the only real cost of allocating memory.  Depends heavily on what else is running on the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant as mentioned I ran the installed version... The debug is taking forever to complete. The file latency doesnt take much. I tested using different setup (SSD, regular disk, network) and the tree is very compactly represented on the disk (like how you would represent a tree with an array only using indices). Thanks for the hint on paging, I will look further in that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, frequent small allocations are a waste of time and memory.

For every allocation, there is overhead:

- Function call preparation
- Function call (break in execution path; possible reload of execution
  pipeline).
- Algorithm to find a memory block (searching perhaps).
- Allocating the memory (marking the block as unavailable).
- Placing the address into a register
- Returning from the function (another break in sequential execution).

Regardless of your machine's speed, the above process is a lot of execution to allocate a small block of memory.

Modern processors love to keep their data close (as in a data cache).  Their performance increases when they can fetch data from the cache and not fetch outside the processor (access times slow down the further away the values are, such as memory on chip, outside core; memory off chip on the same board; memory on other boards; memory on devices (such as Flash and hard drive).  Reallocating memory defeats the effectiveness of the data cache.

The Operating System may get involved and slow down your program.  In the allocation or delete functions, the O.S. may check for *paging*.  Paging, in a simple form, is the swapping of memory areas with areas on the hard drive.  This may occur when other higher priority tasks are running and demand more memory.

An algorithm for speeding up data access:

1. Load data from memory into local variables (registers if possible).
2. Process the data in the local variables (registers).
3. Store the finished data.

If you can, place data into structures.  Load all the structure members at once.  Structures allow for data to be placed into contiguous memory (which reduces the need to reload the cache).

Lastly, reduce branching or changes in execution.  Research "loop unrolling".  Your compiler may perform this optimization at higher optimization settings.